can't divide traffic into two backendBuckets in same domain with google load balancer
I'm serving my React-built page with GCP using bucket. I just made a version2 page and want to go through a/b test. so i want to divide traffic into 50:50 who enters same domain.
so I tried do it in google cloud load balancer YAML editor
defaultService: projects/${projectName}/global/backendBuckets/${backEndBucket1Name}
name: matcher1
routeRules:
  - matchRules:
      - prefixMatch: /
    priority: 1
    routeAction:
      weightedBackendServices:
        - backendService: projects/${projectName}/global/backendBuckets/${backEndBucket1Name}
          weight: 50
        - backendService: projects/${projectName}/global/backendBuckets/${backEndBucket2Name}
          weight: 50

and it keep fails. error logs says my url map resource is invalid.
I also tried updating lb itself by gcloud cli
with following urlmap.yaml
{
  "defaultService": "projects/${projectName}/global/backendBuckets/${backEndBucket1Name}",
  "fingerprint": "${myFingerPrint}",
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "hosts": [
        "${my-hosting-domain-name}"
      ],
      "pathMatcher": "matcher1"
    }
  ],
  "name": "${my-lb-name}",
  "pathMatchers": [
    {
      "defaultService": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${projectName}/global/backendBuckets/${backEndBucket1Name}",
      "name": "matcher1",
      "routeRules": [
        {
          "matchRules": [
            {
              "prefixMatch": "/"
            }
          ],
          "priority": 1,
          "routeAction": {
            "weightedBackendServices": [
              {
                "backendService": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${projectName}/global/backendBuckets/${backEndBucket1Name}",
                "weight": 50
              },
              {
                "backendService": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${projectName}/global/backendBuckets/${backEndBucket2Name}",
                "weight": 50
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

i tried creating, editing existing one and all my tries failed. anyone can help me? T_T
I'm serving my React-built page with GCP using bucket. I just made a version2 page and want to go through a/b test. so i want to divide traffic into 50:50 who enters same domain.

Which type of load balancer do you use?

I'm using external type load balancer
